# Lizmap editor won't save edits to pgsql

Tags: postgis, postgresql, php, lizmap

So I have successfully installed Lizmap, Qgis-server, Apache, and a BigSQL postgreSQL database and published a map with a working WFS pointed at a PostGIS enabled table in my database.  When I try to save an edit in Lizmap it gives me a non descriptive error.  When looking at the network calls in developer console in Chrome it seems to hang on the sending the edit to the database.  I have installed php-pgsql on my Ubuntu Xenial server but I think it is looking in a directory where it expects PostgreSQL to be when my BigSQL is in a different place.  Is there a way to point php-pgsql to look at a different directory?  Has anyone else tried this type of install and made it work and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the problem, Lizmap really doesn't like PostgreSQL UUID fields even if they are allowed to be null and you hide the field so nobody can enter anything into them.  The Lizmap logs really helped.

Comment: Please write a detailed ticket on their github page => https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client/issues. Thanks.